# Using Django and s3boto, some admin images (icon_clock.gif & icon_calendar.gif) don't display

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto

All files, including those not displaying correctly, are present in my bucket at amazon.  The only two images I've found that don't display are icon_clock.gif and icon_calendar.gif.  Everything else works properly.

When I examine the link location of the broken images, I get this:

```
 https://my_bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/admin?Signature=MY_SIGNATURE&AWSAccessKeyId=MY_KEYimg/icon_clock.gif
```

As you can see, the query parameters aren't being added to the end but instead to the middle of the link.

Here are the relevant settings:

```
import os.path

ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
PROJECT_NAME = os.path.basename(ROOT_DIR)

def ABS_PATH(*args):
    return os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, *args)

STATIC_ROOT = ABS_PATH('static')

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'MY_KEY'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'MY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my_bucket_name'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
S3_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STATIC_URL = S3_URL
```

Comment: We're suffering from the same issue and it is discussed here: http://code.larlet.fr/django-storages/issue/121/s3boto-admin-prefix-issue-with-django-14 I'll probably get around to trying one of the proposed solutions there in the next days.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?  I've got the same thing happening and am having luck resolving.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be fixed in the current development version of django-storages. See [issue 121](http://code.larlet.fr/django-storages/issue/121/s3boto-admin-prefix-issue-with-django-14) for more information.

Quick workaround steps:

1. Replace `django-storages` in your requirements.txt with `-e hg+https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages@e27c8b61ab57e5afaf21cccfee005c980d89480f#egg=django_storages-dev`
2. In your settings, add `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False`. The result of this setting is that the AWS auth stuff is not included in every URL. Do this only if all files in your S3 bucket are public.