# Django Admin, Amazon S3, Heroku -- missing icon_calendar

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-s3, django-storage

Okay, I've been learning Django but am a beginner with the framework.  I'm a fan.  I have a build running on heroku with the static files being served from Amazon S3 using Django-storages.  It was very easy to get up and running with no difficulties.

However, I'm missing the calendar icons.  Checking the source shows there's no trailing slash between admin & img.

*Example:*

https://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku-sdbhvaehv/adminimg/icon_clock.gif

*Its a bug apparently in Django-storages listed here:*

http://code.larlet.fr/django-storages/issue/121/s3boto-admin-prefix-issue-with-django-14

And I've implemented the various fixes that are listed in the comments with no luck.

*I've found two posts around on SO and Google Groups but there is no solutions.*

[Using Django and s3boto, some admin images (icon_clock.gif & icon_calendar.gif) don't display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149815/)

So -- I'm looking for any solutions on how to get this icon fixed.  I don't care if I have to modify something after every push, or do whatever - but I can't have a missing calendar icon.

Any help out there?

Comment: This hack is probably a complete non-starter but can you inject a little jquery into the pages?  Iterate over all img elements, test their src attribute and fix as necessary?  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery

Comment: In a pinch, that was something I was thinking about.

Comment: Or even more hacky (yuk) store a copy of icon_clock.gif at https://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku-sdbhvaehv/adminimg/?

Comment: It may be yuk, but I'm trying to get a fix - not solve the world's problems.  Putting an image there with a readme.txt is fine with me.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm a bit embarrassed I didn't think of it while I was working on this thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The problem is not with boto, or with django-storages.

The problem is that the django admin is missusing the `{% static %}` tag. The static tag assumes (rightly) that it is viewing the entire url, and that it can modify that url arbitarily. By passing in only a prefix, the django admin is breaking that contract (which will not be detected in the simplest cases, but will be a big problem when you try to do anything more complex.

You should file a bug or patch against django to explicitly pass all asset urls, in full, to the static tag, and dump these full resource URIs into the javascript context.

EDIT: This solution should work for you:
http://code.larlet.fr/django-storages/issue/121/s3boto-admin-prefix-issue-with-django-14#comment-1604389

Just make sure you have `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH` set to `False`, or you will get querystrings sandwiched in there.

Comment: +1 for the comment.  Is there a suggested fix that I can do in the meantime?

Comment: Thank you.  I've tried both of those solutions with no fix.  I'll review them again today and see what I did wrong.

Comment: what output do you get when you use both of these together?

Comment: It's fixed in the current development version. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18698270/284318